# Read text file line by line from mounted path in Scala

Tags: scala, jupyter-notebook, azure-data-lake-gen2

I intend to read a csv file line by line from a mount path, perform some operations on each line and then write it back to a new csv file. Using below to read the file but it says file not found. I am able to read the file in a dataframe but fail to do so with below code.

```
import scala.io.Source

val filename = "/mnt/jomount/ProductDetails.csv"
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
    println(line)
}
```

Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/jomount/ProductDetails.csv (No such file or directory)
```

Would also like to know how can we perform some operation on each line(line by line as I need to check something!) and write it back to a new csv file

Answer (score 0):

In Scala 2.13, you could use the following snippet:

```
import java.io._
import scala.util.Using
Using(new PrintWriter(new File("out.csv" ))) { file =>
    for (line <- Source.fromFile("in.csv").getLines) {
        process(line) // given that "process(string: String)" is in scope
        file.println(line)
    }
}
```

In previous versions of Scala, you would have to handle exceptions and `close()`ing yourself.

As for the missing file: I am going to be cheeky and assume that the path you supplied does, in fact, not refer to an existing file.